# Time Complexity of two different recursive functions call each other

Tags: time-complexity, runtime, big-o

What is the best way to analyze the time Complexity of two different recursive functions that call each other.

```
class test {
public:
    static int f(int x) {
        if(x < 1) return 1;
        return f(x - 1) + g(x);
    }
    
    static int g(int x) {
        if(x < 2) return 1;
        return f(x - 1) + g(x / 2);
    }
    
};
```

What is the time complexity of test.f(n) here?

I was trying to draw a recursion tree. The height of my recession tree is n. For each level, there are two function calls, i.e, f and g. I tried to substitute g(x) with f(x - 1) + g(x / 2).
So for each function call of f(x) will create two new branches of f(x - 1) and one g(x / 2).
I just got lost, what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

This was really messy, but I believe this is correct - if it isn't I would be very happy to fix this.
(I really hoped StackOverflow would apply LaTeX only to to these kind of questions.)

---

We first need to formulate these two recursive functions, so by the definition in your code, we can write these two as so:

[image]

We can then substitute `g(n)` to the first recursive function `f`:

[image]

---

But what is `g(n/2)` ? Well, by definition it is:

[image]

Again, what is `g(n/4)` ? ... We get the idea, it keeps on and on until we hit `g(1)` - that happens after about `~lg(n)` "cycles" as we want to solve this equation:
[image]

---

So finally, we get this final recursive call for `f`:

[image]

Note that I did not add the `-1` inside `f` as it does not really affect the asymptotic notation here.

We then can solve it by using:

[image]

[image]

The first one can be done using the [iteration method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZlak1awbRk&ab_channel=randerson112358) while the latter can be solved using the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

---

For simplicity, I've written down the code in Python

```py
def f(x):
    if x < 1:
        return 1
    return f(x-1) + g(x)
    
def g(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 1
    return f(x-1) + g(x/2)

iterations = 40
for i in range(1, iterations + 1):
    print(f'i={i}')
    solvefn = f(i)
    print(f'Actual: {solvefn}')
    guess_c = solvefn / 2 ** i
    print(f'c={guess_c}')
    print('------------')
```

And wanted to see how it goes by comparing the solution of `f(n)` for some `n`s to `2 ** n` and this is what I got (Note that my computation power is not so high, the these two recurrence relations are very expensive, because if the solution is right, it is exponential runtime)

```
i=28
Actual: 527053651
c=1.9634278528392315
------------

i=29
Actual: 1054123325
c=1.9634576980024576
------------

i=30
Actual: 2108278696
c=1.9634875431656837
------------
```

---

Meaning that our guess of `2**n` is actually smaller by a factor of about a half, however, recall the definition of the [big-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) we can choose any finite constant `c`, and so we can choose `c=2` to 'fix' this.

---

### Addendum

Because the Akra-Bazzi needs a certain `p` value that would solve this sum:

[image]

At first I thought `p=0` would solve it, which is nonsense (that happened because I evaluated the sum first, then tried to solve it for `p`) - For any matter, I don't think it should overcome `O(2 ** n)` but I don't have a formal proof for that, maybe more calculations should be thought of.

---

### Addendum V.2

I think I might've found a way to solve it, we need to find a `p` that would solve the sum in the addendum above, of-course, this is a well known geometric series that converges to `1` only if `p=1` (and `n` approaches infinity, as we want because we are talking about asymptotical notations), [there is a nice visual proof here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Using this, we can solve it by using the Akra-Bazzi method:

[image]